# How to access windows hierarchy for my application on Mac?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I mean all the windows which belong to my application (process). I need to get something like (NSWindow *) for all of them. Notice, some windows were created by third-party plug-ins and are not accessible by [NSApp windows]. Yes, I know, Quartz Window Services can return all the windows by PID. But how can I get NSWindow by CGWindowID then? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you meant by "your application"? Is it the application you're writing, or all the applications you launch on your mac?

Comment: I clarified the question itself.

Comment: What do you mean by “some windows … created by third-party plug-ins … are not accessible by [NSApp windows]”? Can you name examples?

Comment: OK, I'll explain this on another process.
For example, if you invade into xorg.x.X11 application via SIMBL plug-in and call [[NSApp windows] count] there, you always get 2, despite the real amount of running X clients. Seems like the clients' windows were created somehow different than [[NSWindow alloc] init...]. But they are accessible with Quartz Window Services API. So how to get references to them inside X11 process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `NSWindowList()` will give window ids. Also there're [Quartz Window Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html) to help.

- To get `NSWindow*` (Cocoa) there's `[NSApp windowWithWindowNumber: (NSInteger)windowID]` method.
- To get `WindowRef` (Carbon) there's `HIWindowFromCGWindowID()` function.

If both of the above do not work, that means the window was created with CoreGraphics Private API. Its definition [is available](http://code.google.com/p/undocumented-goodness/source/browse/trunk/CoreGraphics/CGSPrivate.h) thanks to reverse engineering.

Concerning X11 windows on Mac, they are created with Xplugin library (by Xquartz) which is closed source and also uses CoreGraphics Private API.

Answer (score 3):

Try `NSWindowList` to get window numbers, and then `-[NSApplication windowWithWindowNumber:]` to get NSWindows.

Comment: NSWindowList returns correct number of windows from all applications, but windowWithWindowNumber (Cocoa) and HIWindowFromCGWindowID (Carbon) return nil.

Comment: This is the right answer -- NSWindowList returns all windows for all processes, so if windowWithWindowNumber returns nil it means that the window doesn't belong to your application. NSWindowListForContext returns only the windows for a particular process, but you need to call a private method ([NSApp contextID]) to pass in the the context ID for your running application.